# Is there a way to find every index of an input value in a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I've been trying to make a function in python that returns the x,y coordinate of every recurring value in a 2d array. For example if I had the array and a value,

```
array = [ [1 ,2 ,3]
          [2 ,3 ,1]
          [3 ,2, 1]]

search = 1
```

it would output `(0,0) (1,2) (2,2)`

I've been trying to use some functions such as np.where or converting it into a pandas data frame and searching that way, but I'm not sure the best way to do it. When I use np.where, it returns an empty array because I'm using long decimals. I'm trying to do this on an array thats 200 x 200.

Comment: `where` is only as good as the condition array.  If `array==.01` isn't true anywhere, then the result of `where` will be empty.  Searching for exact matches of float values is unreliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do `np.where` PS : a is your array

```
list(zip(*np.where(a==search)))
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

As hpaulj mentioned

```
np.argwhere(np.isclose(a,search))
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Whats the best way to do this if I have a long decimal? When I do this it outputs an empty array.

Comment: @JacksonFuson `list(zip(*np.where(np.isclose(a,search))))`

Comment: `np.argwhere(cond)` does `np.transpose(np.where(cond))`.  Your `zip(*)` is a list version of transpose.

Comment: For further use as an index, the result of `where` is usually more useful than its transpose.  That tuple of arrays is designed from indexing.